# Add data to custom django user model

Tags: python, django

I am new to web devolopment and django. Currently I am developing a simple dashboard web application for our computational cluster and have configured a custom user model, which looks like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
processor_hours = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

All of the default user fields are taken from our ldap server, and authentication works. However, I want to add data to the custom field for each user. I have a text file with the information in columns,

```
username1 hours
username2 hours
```

I tried using the manage.py shell to run a python script and add the data to the corresponding fields but it doesn't seem to be saving it to the database. What am I missing?

Edit: I wasn't saving the user with .save(). The issue is resolved, thanks for the help.

Comment: You have to save both objects, the user **and** the profile via `.save()`

Comment: How are you saving it?